# My Thinkpad X230T only boots on alternate tries

Tags: boot, thinkpad, hibernate

I have a ThinkPad [X230T](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/x230t_x230it_hmm_en_0b48730_02.pdf) with [Debian testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) installed. As the title says, it only boots every other time.

What I mean by this is that I turn it on, I work with it normally, and then I either shut it down or hibernate it. The next time it won't boot. I will press the power button (or open the lid) and both the power and wireless lights will turn on, but nothing else will happen. The screen won't turn on, no disk activity, nothing (I've checked with running an ssh server to see if it was just a display issue, but it definitely isn't). I turn it off and on, and now everything works normally again... until the next time :)

It happens practically every time. I can't seem to reproduce it if I do it a bunch of times in a short period of time, though; it has to be turned off for a while.

I upgraded the BIOS but nothing changed.

What could be the problem?  What should I look at?

Comment: Try detaching the battery for 30 seconds before booting it. Does that make a difference?

Comment: it is important to find out if this is hardware problem or software. can you try same steps without HDD and / or if possible booting stable live linux distro of USB ? do post result

Comment: how do you turn it off? by long pressing the power button or by removing battery?

Comment: Hi. As I commented in the below answer, resetting the BIOS settings *seems* to have fixed the issue, but I keep testing.

Having the battery inserted or not made no difference. 
I didn't try without the hard drive but I did try booting from a USB and the issue kept happening.
I turn it off by long pressing the power button, but actually it feels like a shorter-than-normal press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the BIOS defaults? If not, can you try resetting them?

Are you getting any beeps during start-up (successful or otherwise), running, or shutdown? See page 34 of that manual for beep codes.

One thing I *believe* could cause this is a device not responding to the power-on self test (POST) in time. BIOSes sometimes allow you to change this timeout. Try increasing this if available.

I'm not sure whether fans are part of POST, but it might be getting stuck. You could try cleaning it (a vacuum seems to work, but I'm not sure that's always safe).

If none of these work, you could try checking all the cables for loose connections, but of course this requires a whole other level of care.

Comment: Hi, I tried resetting the BIOS settings a couple days ago and, unbelievably, it worked. I also can't belive I didn't try this myself, I guess sometimes you need someone else to point out the obvious for you. I'll keep testing for a few more days and accept the answer if it keeps working. I was getting no beeps of any kind by the way.